# Parse.com subclassing in Swift 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

My question is about a bridge header that does not seem to work in Swift 2. I copied this code strait from the Parse.com iOS guide into xCode to see if it would work.

```
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

class Armor : PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Armor"
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. I get an error on the `#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>` line with the error `Consecutive statements of a line must be separated by ';'`. So, my question is how I would go about subclassing in Parse.com with Swift 2. I have looked around the internet and haven't found anything. I think that there may have been a change in how Swift imports bridge headers, but I am not at all sure because I have never used a bridge header before. So, I could be doing something idiotic. Anyway, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all make sure you have the latest **Parse** SDK. If you have the latest SDK you can create a **PFObject Subclass** like this;

```
class Armor: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

static func parseClassName() -> String {
      return "Armor"
   }
}
```

When you create your custom Subclass, you should register your subclass to Parse SDK in **AppDelegate** like this;

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        //Registering SubClasses
        Armor.registerSubclass()

        // Initialize Parse.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
        Parse.setApplicationId("Your API Key", clientKey: "Your Client Key")

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Post SDK release 1.14.0 you should not need to register subclasses.

See the changelog from https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/releases/tag/1.14.0.

There is also discussion of this issues in [#1023](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1023) and 1035 where removing the calls to registerSubclass() has resolved looping problems in PFUser.